# Django advanced tutorials

Tags: django

I just did the advanced tutorials of django of making reusable apps and after creating the package when I try to run the server again that got closed as I changed my directory from polls to django-polls . It showed the error as following:

> No such file or directory:
>   'C:\python\mysite\django-polls\django-polls\dist\django-polls-0.1.tar.gz'

The commandline code was :

```
pip install --user django-polls/dist/django-polls-0.1.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't write right path.
It's simple to write your code in `dist/` directory - where your `tar.gz` file is.

In `dist/` directory, just write

```
$pip install --user django-polls-0.1.tar.gz
```

good luck!